# IntelliJ TypeScript Structural Search

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, structural-search

Is it possible to define a structural search in IntelliJ to warn about the use of the native JavaScript `String` class instead of the Typescript `string` type? The typescript documentation recommends that you never use the native JavaScript types (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object)).

Our team is going back and forth between Kotlin and Typescript code so it is easy to inadvertently use `String`. I would want to detect this in places like function parameters, variables, and as fields in classes.

For some more clarity on what I am interested in doing:

```js
class MyTypescriptClass {
  myField: String;         //Inspection would generate warning on this line.
  anotherField: string;    //Inspection would not generate warning on this line.

  fun1(param: String) {}   //Inspection would generate warning on this line.

  fun2(param: string) {}   //Inspection would not generate warning on this line.
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what it should and shouldn't warn on?

Comment: Updated to add additional detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the short template `String` should do it. Make sure the Match Case checkbox is checked.
[image: Structural Search Dialog]

Comment: This seems to work fine. I was obviously trying to think too much into this and over complicate it by trying to restrict to just variable/parameter declarations. This seems like it should work for what I want. Thanks.